# How to run window function in pysprak

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have structure like this . I want group by data based on  ENTER12333_NUM and mark RECALC_ENTER12333_CALCUALTION as Y if under that group we have any row_operation as I/U/D .

```
+---------+---------+--------------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------------+
|CURR_COL1|CURR_COL2|          HASH_VALUE|        CURR_COL3|CURR_COL4|       CURR_COL45|ENTER12333_NUM|RECALC_ENTER12333_CALCUALTION|ROW_OPERATION|WINNER_IN222222|
+---------+---------+--------------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------------+
|    75757|    hello|9bc7d98d527bb54b1...|    79.0000000000|       pb|    55.0000000000|440.0000000000|                         null|            I|           null|
|       46|    hello|9bc7d98d527bb54b1...|    79.0000000000|       pb|    55.0000000000|590.0000000000|                         null|            I|           null|
|     4545| Senorita|d95ee5d8db9958f6e...|    79.0000000000|     null|    79.0000000000|590.0000000000|                         null|            U|           null|
|   189899|    hello|a93d52dad9dcc3bd0...|    79.0000000000|  Purnima|    79.0000000000|890.0000000000|                         null|            N|           null|
|   234223|  goodbye|4271325117076d7b5...|454646.0000000000|   bhatia|454646.0000000000|890.0000000000|                         null|            D|           null|
+---------+---------+--------------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

I can write sql query for same

```
     select a.*, case when ( sum(case when ROW_OPERATION in ('I','U','D') then 1 else 0 end ) over (partition by ENTER12333_NUM) ) > 0 then 'Y' else 'N' end RECALC_ENTER12333_CALCUALTION
                  from delta_firmographic_data a
```

How can we do it in pyspark dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time you can rewrite sqls to dataframe but some practice is needed to identify some tricks.

Please take a look at my example. I am using only one row and i do not really care about data type. Your dataframe is to wide and i dont want to rewrite it by hand. If you need example with more test data please provide them in python

Anyway, this should do the trick or at least be a good starting point for you :)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = [
    {
        "CURR_COL1": "75757",
        "CURR_COL2": "hello",
        "HASH_VALUE": "9bc7d98d527bb54b1",
        "CURR_COL3": "79.0000000000",
        "CURR_COL4": "pb",
        "CURR_COL45": "55.0000000000",
        "ENTER12333_NUM": "440.0000000000",
        "RECALC_ENTER12333_CALCUALTION": "null",
        "ROW_OPERATION": "I",
        "WINNER_IN222222": "null",
        "CURR_COL4": "01/01/2022",
        "CURR_COL45": "1",
    },
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

df.withColumn(
    "RECALC_ENTER12333_CALCUALTION",
    F.when(F.sum(
        F.when(
            F.col("ROW_OPERATION").isin(F.lit("I"), F.lit("U"), F.lit("D")), F.lit(1)
        ).otherwise(F.lit(0))
    ).over(Window.partitionBy("ENTER12333_NUM")) > 0, F.lit("Y")).otherwise(F.lit("N")),
).show()
```

output:

```
+---------+---------+-------------+----------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------------+
|CURR_COL1|CURR_COL2|    CURR_COL3| CURR_COL4|CURR_COL45|ENTER12333_NUM|       HASH_VALUE|RECALC_ENTER12333_CALCUALTION|ROW_OPERATION|WINNER_IN222222|
+---------+---------+-------------+----------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------------+
|    75757|    hello|79.0000000000|01/01/2022|         1|440.0000000000|9bc7d98d527bb54b1|                            N|            I|           null|
+---------+---------+-------------+----------+----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing query. One quick do we really need part_sum in between for calculation. Can't we do it in one go ?

Comment: is it mandatory to make pseudo column part_sum in between

Comment: It can be inside, i wanted to show step by step what is happening. You can just copy formula for part_sum in place of col.("part_sum"), please check updated answer